# where is tensorflow:Assets file location?

Tags: tensorflow

I recently created a prototype model in tensorflow, I'm asking if where is the saved model saved in my pc, its file location. saving my file outputted this info:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: m_translator\assets
```

and I don't know what clearly this is hope there's someone who can explain this to me

Answer (score 1):

From the info you have given, it says that the files are written to m_translator. Once check in your PC in the same directory where you are running your code if there is any folder named m_translator or check in the filepath you have provided while saving the model. Thank You.